# Separating database operations in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application with several projects: the main project of the application (WebApp) and a database class library with models and `db_context`. In the database library I want to add all the operations methods, like save, update and delete.

But no matter what I try, I cannot get this to work; this is the method that I have:

`MyProject.Data` class library

```
public class DbOps
{
    public static async Task<bool> SaveCustomerChangesToDb(DbContext context, Model model, object objectToSave)
    {
       context.model.Add(objectToSave);
       await context.SaveChangesAsync();
       // some more logic...
       return true;
    }
}
```

That method gets called in the controller, but this just causes errors. How can I write a model-agnostic method to save changes in this class, that I can use with multiple view models and database models?

I'm using EF en Net Core 2.1. In the `MyProject.WebApp` project I have set references to the data class library correctly. All the migrations also went fine, for example, I can add data manually in the SQL editor in VS2019.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to recreate the repository pattern

Comment: looking into that now, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
 public static async Task<bool> SaveCustomerChangesToDb<TEntity>(DbContext context, TEntity objectToSave) where TEntity:class
    {
       context.Set<TEntity>().Add(objectToSave);
       await context.SaveChangesAsync();
       // some more logic...
       return true;
    }
```